# showing a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is not second countable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b]:-\infty<a<b<\infty\}$

(a)show $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for some topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

(b) show the $\mathbb{R}$ with the generated topology is first countable but not second countable.

(c)$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t to the generated topology.

My approach of proof:
(a) We only have to show that for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a set in $\mathcal{B}$ that contains $x$ and any $x$ in the intersection of 2 open sets in the generated topology contains another set from $\mathcal{B}$ . The first condition is trivial, since if $x\in \mathbb{R}$ it is contained in some interval. For the second condition, take $U, V \in \mathcal{T(B)}$ then $U,V $ are finite intersections of half-open intervals, which are also half-open intervals. So we have $U=(a,b], V=(c,d]$ then take any $x\in U\cap V$(assuming the intersection is non empty). The intersection itself is already a set in $\mathcal{B}$ since $U\cap V=(c,b]$ and it contains $x$. Hence we shown $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for some topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

(b)I'm stucked on showing there exists a countable neighborhood base at each $x$ of $\mathbb{R}$, but I think it has to do with $\mathbb{Q}$. So I want to say that, if we define $\mathcal{N}=\{U: U \in \mathcal{T},x\in U\}\cap\mathbb{Q}$, clearly this is a neighborhood base of $\mathcal{T}$ at $x$ and it is countable because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. Now, for not second countable, assume to the contrary that it is second countable. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a countable base for $\mathcal{T}$, then for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ , $\exists U_x \in \mathcal{E}$ such that $x\in U_x \subset (a,x]$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. if $x\neq y$ then we have $U_x\neq U_y$. Hence, $card(\{U_x:x\in \mathbb{R}\})=card(\mathbb{R})$ which is uncountable. Which means $\mathcal{E}$ is uncountable. A contradiction, so it must not be second countable.

(c) not sure what we need to show for this.

Can anyone give some hints or help me out here? This isn't a homework problem, just working out on question from back of a chapter of Folland's analysis book.

Comment: Don't (b) and (c) contradict each other? $\mathbb Q$ is a countable dense set , so the space is separable. BTW, separable is not the same as second countable in general topological spaces  (though these are equivalent in metric spaces).

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for noting that. I meant in b, not second countable instead of not separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) Given $x$ choose  a sequence of  rational numbers $r_n $ increasing to $x$ and a sequence of  rational numbers $s_n $ decreasing to $x$. Verify that $(r_n,s_n], n \geq 1$ is a base at $x$ for this topology.

(c) Any interval $(a,b] \in \mathbb B$ contains a rational number . Hence, any non-empty open set in this topology also contains a rational number.  This proved (c).